# Jquery Mobile Dynamic content get lost on page refresh

Tags: jquery, mobile, dynamic, refresh

I have the attached code. When I refresh the page manually pressing F5, the dynamic content get lost . How do I keep the list <foo> content after refresh? . When I load the page the first time I can see the `<li>` foo .

```
<?php
session_start();
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">    

        <ul class="Offline" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="c">
            <li class="Offlinediv" data-role="list-divider">Users Offline</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page Two</a></li>
        </ul>

<?php

 //********
 // Connect to the database  
 //  left join users users and users online .

 // while($column = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
 $column['userid']='ABBM';  // hardcode for testing
 //{ 

 //user status not known

      if (!isset($_SESSION[$column['userid']])){
           $_SESSION[$column['userid']]='offline' ; 
   ?>
          <script>
          $(".Offline").append('<li class="<?php echo $column['userid'];?>"><a href="#page">foo</a></li>');
          $(".Offline").listview('refresh');
          </script>
     <?php

             } 
        //else statement 
        //the code is not complete  
// }

  ?>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Similar to this question, with answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189052/jquerymobile-refresh-ajax-loaded-page/16038099#16038099